# translate php date?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

Im my view I use last-access field for users. I use custom date format (only d) The resulot is for example 1 day 14 hours. 
Question: how to translate it to different language? I am not using any localization module besides strings overrides (and I do not want to install any additional module just to translate it)

Thank you for help

Comment: How are you translating the rest of the view?

Comment: @PatrickKenny I just want to translate words that are visible to visitors. Not UI.

Comment: But is the date the only item in the view that needs to be translated?  If not, how are you translating the rest of the view?

Comment: @PatrickKenny yes, it is the only thing. For other things I just use custom text field.